# JNI Wrapping another Library

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, wrapper

I'm new to this, but basically here's my situation: I've developed a few months ago an application in Java that runs with Kinect. Now we need to migrate the application to Kinect 2. To do this, I must write a wrapper on the existent Kinect 2 SDK.

I started reading JNI tutorials 2 days ago, and so far I can do wrap my own C++ code, but when it comes to other libraries I can't, and here's what I'm trying to do:

Right now, before going to the Kinect 2 SDK I am trying to do a small wrapper on something that I'm already used (OpenCV). I have written a small class (that has only a learning purpose) that initializes an image using the OpenCV code written in C++. When I try to build a DLL everything works fine, but when I try to run with my Java code I get "%1 Not a Valid Win32 Application". If I comment every line that uses the OpenCV code then I get no error and can run the other functions that does not have OpenCV in my wrapper.

I imagine that the problem is some bad configuration.

What I'm using is:

- Netbeans (Java)
- Visual Studio 2013 (C++)

Comment: The other reason for such an error is that you're loading a 64-bit module while running as a 32-bit app.

Comment: I would like a little more information on what you are compiling, how you are compiling it, and how java is interacting with it.  How did you call you Java application?  How did Java load and use the native functions?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect candidate for the JavaCPP Presets: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Create-New-Presets

Answer (score 1):

Your java machine runs on either 32 or 64 bit.

Your dll needs to be compiled for the same machine as the java machine :

- if you run on a 32 bit java machine you will need a 32 bit dll (even if the system is x64)
- if you run on a 64 bit java machine you will need a 64 bit dll (the system can only be x64)

In visual studio check your platform for which you are compiling the dll . It should match the jre you are using in netbeans.

Comment: Ii already checked and everything is fine. As I wrote, I can use wrapped methods as long as it does not include the OpenCV library, otherwise it throws me the error. If I try to compile the dll for 32 bits none of the wrapped functions work and it gives me another error: "Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform"

Comment: By your wrapper you are meaning the C++ wrapper, correct ? And by commenting every line you mean commenting every line in C++? If it's C++ , then your wrapper might use dependencies on OpenCV.dll. Try loading OpenCV.dll prior to loading your wrapper library inside Java. There might be a problem along the dll dependency tree.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant, I'm going to try that out. Should I load the dll in java?

Comment: The problem might be that one of the dll dependencies of your wrapper isn't satisfied when you are loading the dll. There are tools like DllDependencyWalker that will allow you to see to what Dlls is your Dll dynamically linked. If when you try to load your dll in your Java machine it fails to find the required dlls (or proper versions of the dlls) it will fail. A fast approach would be to copy all OpenCV dlls and their dependency to system32 and see what happens.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks :D Instead of putting the DLLs in the System32, I put it in the root of the java project and it worked (didn't tried to put them in the System32)